# Store object of Drawable class in database

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use **IconDialog** library to set an icon to my ImageView which user will set them. This library will return a Drawable object. I had no problem working with this library when I had no database as I just called setDrawable function and passed the returned drawable to it, but now I want to store a reference of this drawable to database and I can't find any methods in Drawable.class to get reference of drawable or something and I couldn't find any functions in the library which returns any reference. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all whose working with this library and have same problem as me. I found the answer by exploring on the library codes. There is a class called **Icon** which the **IconDialog** returns instances of this variable. As Icon's constructor is private you can't instantiate from that class so you should first convert them to **Drawable** then convert those **Drawables** to **Bitmap** (if you don't know how checkout [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)).

And for storing **Bitmap** in DataBase you can simply convert **Bitmap** to **String** using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715427/how-to-implement-sqlite-database-to-store-bitmap-image-and-text).
*Or store Bitmap in file then store the link or any other ways you know.*

Hope this solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Resource.getIdentifier`

```
int imgId = res.getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: That library doesn't add the icon drawable to my project it just send me back an object of Drawable class

Comment: I know what you want, I think you need to modify the library to change the return as resourceName and include on yout project

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to store a Drawable in your SQLite database?
You could go with

```
val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.drawable.minus_vector_black)
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()        
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
val iconAsByteArray = stream.toByteArray()
```

and then save that to your database as a BLOB

(code shamelessly stolen from [converting Java bitmap to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array/36791309))

Comment: Yea but the drawable is not in my project as R.drawable.XXX. It's just an object of Drawable class.